# Union undefined vs type guards

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Given strict null checking and an interface like

```
export interface Foo {
    a?: string;
    b: string|undefined;
    c: string|null;
    d: string|undefined|null;
}
function bar(foo: Foo) { ... }
```

I expected `a` to behave similarly to either `b`, `c` or `d`.  Instead, I found that `a` behaved differently from all of them.

```
bar({b: undefined, c: null, d: undefined}); // works
bar({c: null, d: undefined}); // 'b' is missing in type '{...}'
bar({b: undefined, d: undefined}); // 'c' is missing in type '{...}'
bar({b: undefined, c: null}); // 'd' is missing in type '{...}'
```

Is this expected behavior?  Is there any way to achieve the optional property behavior on an interface without the `?:` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes, I found [a comment on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9543#issuecomment-230964903) confirming that it's by design:

> This is by design. A property can be omitted only if it was declared
>   with a ? modifier.

Also, it does not depend upon strict null checks being turned on.

> Is there any way to achieve the optional property behavior on an
>   interface without the ?: syntax?

No, presumably because someone might find use for all 4 behaviors from your example.

Comment: Thanks for the source of the "by design".  I'm curious why this is by design though, in my mind `undefined` means `not defined` or `missing`.  If you want `defined/present but not a value` it seems like you want `null`.  Adding yet another way something can be not-a-value makes me sad.

Comment: I don't know the reason. To make things worse, strict null checks make `null` incompatible with optional properties - you can't assign `null` to `Something  | undefined`. This made me switch my code style to `undefined` instead of `null` everywhere. See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9653 for some discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, even with the property `a` assuming the same type of `b` you still need to use the `?` char if you want an optional property.

For the Structural Typing Checking, the type `string|undefined` does not assure that this property is optional.

So, it is the expected behaviour.